# Pre-fill form field via URL in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a simple way to pre-fill a field in my contact form when ever a user clicks on a link that is given in some other page.

This is my contact form in html :

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php" >
    <p>Your name:
    <br /><input name="name" /></p>
    <p>Your email:
    <br /><input name="email" /></p>
    <p>Your message:
    <br /><textarea name="message" id="message" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send" /></p>
</form>
```

I want to fill the "message" field with "some text" when a user clicks on a url like `www.xyz.com/contact.html?setmessagefield=some_text`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

JavaScript has no built-in functions to parse url parameters like that (Since those GET parameters are usually used to send data to the server).
I'd suggest using a hash instead (A hash is purely client-side):

> www.xyz.com/contact.html#name=some_text&email=more%20text

Now, add some `id`'s to your fields:

```
<p>Your name:
<br /><input name="name" id="name" /></p>

<p>Your email:
<br /><input name="email" id="email" /></p>
```

Then set the values like this, on load:

```
var hashParams = window.location.hash.substr(1).split('&'); // substr(1) to remove the `#`
for(var i = 0; i < hashParams.length; i++){
    var p = hashParams[i].split('=');
    document.getElementById(p[0]).value = decodeURIComponent(p[1]);;
}
```

**[Working example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/MEwX6/)**

The big advantage of this is that it's flexible. If you want to set the values of 2 fields, you supply those 2 fields' `id`'s in the hash:

> www.xyz.com/contact.html#name=some_text&email=more%20text

4 fields? 4 id's:

> www.xyz.com/contact.html#name=some_text&email=more%20text&username=john&age=23

No need to edit the code, then.

Comment: What if I have an url like this? 
The hash symbol is inserted at the end of parameters.
[https://it-center.am/?description=B16083&amount=AMD40,000&language=hy#modalpayment]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might want to consider the security issues before implementing: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29598/should-sensitive-data-ever-be-passed-in-the-query-string

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but when I use this or the answer by alosidg, if I change any field (auto filled or not) all the auto completed fields get cleared. There is other JS on the form (Gmaps auto fill) but this does not happen with the browser auto complete or manually entering the information.

Comment: When you use this answer, does the data get entered when you load the page? If the data disappears after that, that could be the browser’s autocomplete clearing the fields.

Comment: The data gets entered but as soon as I type a character in a prefilled or empty field it clears and will not come back. No signs of chrome auto complete trying to fill the form. The fields useally highlight when auto complete is filling them in. Plus a dropdown useally shows in the box I am typing in. I am using a userscript to add this function to a 3rd party page. The same thing happens With this answer and the URL() constructor answer below.

Comment: The "working example" link does not exist.

Comment: Hey @Cerbrus can you fix the "Working example" link?

Answer (score 28):

A more modern way would be to use the [`URL()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) and the [searchParams property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams). Let the browser engine do the work!

```
(new URL(window.location.href)).searchParams.forEach((x, y) =>
    document.getElementById(y).value = x)
```

[Try it online!](https://jsbin.com/fufutexegi/1/edit?html,js,output) or on Stack Overflow:

```js
const hash = '?name=some_text&email=more%20text';
const example = "http://example.com/" + hash;

(new URL(example)).searchParams.forEach((x, y) =>
    document.getElementById(y).value = x);
```

```html
<p>Your name:
<br /><input name="name" id="name" /></p>

<p>Your email:
<br /><input name="email" id="email" /></p>
```

Comment: Great answer if someone wants to do this to multiple fields (HTML rules doesnt allow same ID), try 
`document.getElementsByName(y).forEach((p) => (p.value = x));
`

Comment: @Rishav Thank you. In your case you can write `document.getElementsByName(y).forEach(p => p.value = x);`

Comment: Note, if it's a checkbox (`type="checkbox"`), the value attribute shouldn't be changed. Instead the "checked" attribute needs to be set.

Comment: Therefore the full lambda expression is: `p => p.type === "checkbox" ? p.checked = (x === "true") : p.value = x`

Answer (score 3):

Don't bother with JavaScript if you're using PHP.

Just add a little something to the HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php" >
  <p>Your name:<br />
  <input name="name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['name']) ?>" /></p>

  <p>Your email:<br />
  <input name="email" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['email']) ?>"/></p>

  <p>Your message:<br />
  <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="10" cols="50">
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['message']) ?>
  </textarea></p>

  <p><input type="submit" value="Send" /></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve your current url with `window.location.href` and then get the default message via a regular expression :

```
var msg = window.location.href.match(/\?setmessagefield=(.*)/);
document.getElementById("message").value = msg[1];
```

Comment: Have you try to see what are in these variables : `console.log(window.location.href)` should give you `www.xyz.com/contact.html?setmessagefield=some_text` and `console.log(msg)` should give you the array : `["?setmessagefield=some_text", "some_text"]`.