# Pre fill form using the URL bar

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a form which I need it to insert data using the URL first for a few fields. I've attached a sample of my form below. We're posting it using PHP into a mySQL database. I don't mind how it gets in there. But i've seen examples using example.com/form.php?add_1=10 The Street, which would be the best way for me.

Thanks,

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" name="epicform">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="surname" required style="
height: 35px;
">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="add_1" name="add1" placeholder="Address Line 1" required style="
height: 35px;
">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="add_2" name="add2" placeholder="Address Line 2" required style="
height: 35px;
">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="add_3" name="add3" placeholder="Address Line 3" required style="
height: 35px;
">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="postcode" name="postcode" placeholder="Postcode" required style="
height: 35px;
">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone_number" name="phoneNum" placeholder="Phone Number" required style="
height: 35px;
">
</form>
```

I've already tried a javascript solution on here, but I couldn't seem to get it to do anything.

Comment: Questions asking for code should **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: I have already tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070105/pre-fill-form-field-via-url-in-html but i can't seem to get it to do anything!

Comment: @JohnConde Whatever happened to that closing option? That was the best one ever. (*I see you've archived it*) ;-) SO should put it back in. +1 (I think I'll keep a copy of it myself).

Comment: I liked it, too, but SO felt there were better ways of doing this. I think this ones sums up the problem *nicely*. Hence, I still use it.

Comment: Yes it does sum it up quite *nicely.* @JohnConde I'm saving it for future use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

http://urlToYourScript.php?add1=Randomstreet

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="add_1" name="add1" 
placeholder="<?php echo $_GET['add1']; ?>" required style="height: 35px;">
```

Comment: Works a treat! Cheers mate!!

Comment: please mark the answer as correct for future references. thanks.

Comment: Done now. Cheers @user3348022

Answer (score 1):

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" name="epicform">

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="add_1" name="add1" value="<?php echo $_GET['add1']; ?>" placeholder="Address Line 1" required style="height: 35px;">

</form>
```

**Now your URL must work!**
http://example.com/form.php?add_1=10