# Fill an input-box by url without editing the receiver page

Tags: javascript, url, input, inputbox

I want to fill an input-box which I don't have any access on it ( so I can't add any javascripts ) with url. 
Something like
:

> http://google.com/#id_searchfield=text

I mentioned google so that you know that the receiver page is not under my control.

Is it possible or not ?

- ### **If it's impossible , Is there a way to do that with another page on a different domain instead of url ? ( some code or .. )**

I have seen these but all of them needs access on the receiver page :

- [Pre-fill form field via URL in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070105/pre-fill-form-field-via-url-in-html)
- [How can I pre-populate html form input fields from url parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422265/how-can-i-pre-populate-html-form-input-fields-from-url-parameters)
- postMessage() Api
- localstorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to send data via an URL you need to find the name of the object you want to fill, so in case of google, you need to go to 
https://www.google.nl/?q=CongratzYouFoundIt
To add spaces replace them with %20, so 
https://www.google.nl/?q=Congratz%20You%20Found%20It%20Again
Other special chars are aviable with HTML special Chars

Comment: So why do some websites don't act like that ? for example : https://github.com/?q=why ( the github search bar name is also "q" )

Comment: Some sites empty all their inputs before outputing the content to prevent what you are trying. I assume this is what happens at github.

Comment: So there is no way to do that with that type of websites?

Comment: Not that I can think of, Sorry

Comment: Thank you for your helpful response anyway.