# Add value to field by URL ?name=data

Tags: javascript, url, input, field, inputbox

You know passing value to field by URL could be done by :

```
?name=data
```

For example :

```
Google.com/?q=stackoverflow
```

And then when you open this link you have "stackoverflow" written in the field.
But I can't do this with some websites.
For example : ( GitHub search bar name is also "q" )

```
github.com/?q=stackoverflow
```

If you open this link there is no text in the search field.
I want to know why and how to make this method work for these websites?

Comment: Those sites actively look at the query string and parse it out. Do a search on github, the format is: `https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=YOURQUERYHERE`

Comment: So what can I do with those websites like Github?

Comment: You look at the url after you search...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site has to parse the data out of the URL and use it to set the `value` attribute of the `input` when they generate the HTML to send to the browser.

Comment: ok what can I do with that websites which don't do this action with query strings ? I mean passing data from URL to fields?

Comment: You could write a browser extension and install it on  your browser.

Comment: I think I didn't ask my question correctly could you please see this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719895/fill-an-input-box-by-url-without-editing-the-receiver-page

Comment: @user1599537: Quentin's comment still applies. You can write a browser extension or user script that does that, but it will work only in your browser then.

Comment: You can read the documentation for writing extensions for whatever browser you are using.