# How can I use “textarea name” to fill the field with a link that i type in browser address bar?

Tags: javascript, php, browser

I got this from a PHP site:

```
<textarea name="Post" style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; height: 200px;" tabindex="3"></textarea>
```

It's a field where you can enter several lines of text. How can I use a link that you type in address bar of browser so if you visit this link it will automatically type a text into this textarea field?

Another example where I got it working:

```
<input type="text" tabindex="2" name="subj" maxlength="64" value="">
```

Here it's simple, I only need to take the name and insert it to the link, like this:

https://example.site.org/pm.php?c=1**&subj=anytext**

But how would it work for the textarea above? I have tried adding **&Post=anytext** but that didn't help me to fill the textarea with text once I visit the link? :/

Here is an image if my problem is unclear but I'm not allowed to make it visible because my low points
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kp3ir.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pre-fill form field via URL in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070105/pre-fill-form-field-via-url-in-html)

Comment: You can make PHP echo the text: `<textarea ..><?= $_GET['message'] ?></textarea>`

Comment: @ChrisG Can you show an example link of how it would look like? I'm looking for a link that I type in address bar of browser that includes some text, where this text will be written onto that textarea field once I visit the link.

Comment: I would look like `https://yourdomain.com/yourscript.php?subj=anytext&message=Hello%20World`

Comment: @ChrisG Is it not possible doing this without a script? Just by using a link that is typed in address bar and once you visit the link it will fill the text fields with some text

Comment: yes, you can do that. if the querystring contains the `subject` parameter and you are trying to use that in the textfield then it will work without a "script"

Comment: Are you asking how to do this with a website operated by a 3rd party?

Comment: @ChrisG Yes it is someone else's website, not mine

Comment: In that case you can't, unless whoever created the site is already putting a GET parameter into the textarea (which is pretty unlikely I guess).