# Autofill Amount and Description on donation site with URL

Tags: javascript, ssl

I'm currently working with a friend to do a donation drive and would like to know if there's a way to autofill the donation page: https://www.convergepay.com/hosted-payments?ssl_txn_auth_token=4G8dYCJVTk%2BZ84twEiUlHgAAAX6SchrL

with specific amount and description

I tried adding adding &ssl_amount=100 to the url but doesn't seem to work
https://www.convergepay.com/hosted-payments?ssl_txn_auth_token=4G8dYCJVTk%2BZ84twEiUlHgAAAX6SchrL&ssl_amount=100

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, from the info we have, it doesn't look like just adding a URL parameter would solve your problem. It looks like we'd also also need some JavaScript on the frontend to parse the URL parameters and autofill the correct input field with the value passed in the URL.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43980063/10213537) did something similar, except for id rather than name. In your case it would be something like:

```
const params = (new URL(window.location.href)).searchParams;
document.getElementById('ssl_amount').value = params.get('ssl_amount');
```

Comment: oh bummer, we don't have a way to modify the donate page as it is using a 3rd party site, I was hoping that a simple url code would be able to fix it. Thank anyways